# Codeigniter is not showing 404 error page

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I'm developing a new website using codeigniter, this is my first codeigniter experience. I suspect that there is something not working with the 404 error, when I try to load a controller that does not exist, or a wrong function of an existing controller, I get back the standard webserver 404 error, and not the codeigniter one.

I did not touch the "404_override" option in the route config file.
Is it normal? I expect (but maybe I'm wrong) that in these cases the show_404() function is called.

Answer (score 1):

Is your .htaccess file correctly set up?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You have to setup an .htaccess file in order to have custom error pages working. Checkout the official [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter should be showing it's 404 page, unless you did not remove the index.php from the URI. In that case you can try to open another file without touching CodeIgniter. Take a look [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) to see how to remove index.php using `.htaccess`.

**Update:**

There seems to be a solution for ISS: ISAPI_Rewrite Lite (free, lite version of a commercial product). I found it [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/95238/#481913)

Comment: I didn't remove the index.php because I'm on a IIS6 web server and there is no way to do that (I checked few minutes ago). In an Apache server the CI error message is correctly loaded while the IIS server keeps showing the old ugly 404 page.

Comment: Edited my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry the question, is the rewrite engine mandatory to make CodeIgniter working properly?I mean, if I do not need to remove in the url the "index.php" segment, why should I set up a rewrite engine?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: So you're defenetly calling all the controllers and methods like this? example.com/index.php/controller/method. If yes, then let's try something different then. CodeIgniter automatically logs any show_404() calls. Enable error logging in CI and then check the log file to see if it's logged.

Comment: thank you again!
Where I will deploy the site (IIS server) I can't set any permission to the log folder. Anyway, I don't think that the log would be useful since seems that when I go to example.com/index.php/controller/wrongMethod (IIS server) CodeIgniter is not "managing" the error as stated by this error:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/391790/404_error.png